# Instant Validation in JS

Tags: javascript, validation, design-patterns, instant

Okay so the thing i want to do is create a JavaScript code that checks the input of the user and sees if it matches the rules and shows an error message instantly next to the text field saying "xxx is not a valid entry"

For example if the rule is that the first character has to be a capital letter, followed by a number and it cant have any special characters.

The user types in something like: "13da2343*" and the result should be "Invalid entry, first character should be a Capital letter and Special characters is an invalid entry." Which should be shown right next to the text field.

I don't have a clue on how to even start this for myself. Please help, I am new to JavaScript

**EDIT**

This is the entire code that I have so far for my website. I dont know how to make it say a specific character entered is invalid and that itself next to the text field.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title> THING </title>
<meta name="Author" content="Dhruvin Desai" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var input = document.getElementsByName('a')[0];

    if (~input.value.search(input.getAttribute('pattern'))) {
        alert('Is valid!');
    } else {
        alert('It's invalid...');
    }
});
}//]]>  

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="response">
    <form id="form" action="#" >
    <fieldset>
    <LEGEND><br>THING</br></LEGEND>

    <!-- Input Fields -->

    <label for="name"> Username </label>
    <input type="text" name="a" value="" id="name" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" required="required" placeholder="Username" pattern="^[A-Z][A-Za-z]{0,11}$" onkeyup="check(this)" />
    <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />

    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
```

**EDIT 2**

I added a new script that works but only accepts CAPITAL letters, which I only want for the first letter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title> IT 202 - Assignment 3 </title>
<meta name="Author" content="Dhruvin Desai" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="response">
    <form id="form" action="insert_form.php">
    <fieldset>
    <LEGEND><br>Assignment 3</br></LEGEND>

    <!-- Input Fields -->

    <label for="name"> Username </label>
    <input name="name" id="name" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" required="required" placeholder="Username" onkeyup="check(this.value)" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />

    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function check(string) 
{
    loop: for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) 
    {
        var res = string.substring(i, i + 1).match(/[A-Z][A-Za-z]{0,11}/);

        if (!res)
        {
            alert("Error on position " + (i + 1) + ":\n This character is no Letter: "+string.substring(i, i + 1));
            break loop;
        }


    }

}
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of "real-time" validation is usually done with a timer that gets fired (and reset) on each keypress. If the timer expires since the user's last key press, validation kicks in.

A 250 ms delay works nicely. If you're new to JavaScript, you should study [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) and [`window.clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout).

Pseudo-code (otherwise, I would be doing all the work for you):

```
when key pressed:
    if existing timeout:
        cancel existing timeout

    fire new timeout

when timeout expired:
    do validation

    if validation failed:
        set error message
        show error message
    else:
        hide error message
```

For the actual validation itself, you can simply add some code to do the validation yourself, or if the validation is regular-expression-worthy, you can use regular expressions. You should study the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object for this.

To show an error message next to a field, one way is to embed an error container in your markup and initially hide it. Upon error, you fill its contents and show the container. You should hopefully know enough CSS to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern` attribute and pass RegExp expression. For older browsers you can use polyfiller like [h5f](https://github.com/ryanseddon/H5F) or [webshim](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim).

Comment: the thing is that I want the error message to be shown instantly (as in as its typed) next to the text field so the user knows what they have typed is wrong.

Comment: webshims has an invelidchange and validchange events that will give you this oppotrunity.

Answer (score 0):

One method could be to add a 'listener' to your form that is checking the form fields periodically. I have done that in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/9ssKZ/), it may be of use for you?

Comment: I cant get the JavaScript code to work when i try to copy all the code and test it out in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

This example of instant validation using javascript in JSP page.

```html
<html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {  

            if((document.getElementById("User").value).length == 0)
            {
                document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "Username is required";
            }

            if((document.getElementById("Password").value).length == 0)
            {
                document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = "Password is required";
            }
            
            var uploadfile = document.getElementById('File');

            if (!(uploadfile .value.match(/pdf$/) || uploadfile .value.match(/PDF$/)))
            {
                document.getElementById("file").innerHTML = "Incorrect file type. Only file type .pdf id allowed";
            }

            if(uploadfile .value == 0)
                {
                document.getElementById("file").innerHTML = "Empty file was uploaded. Please upload a PDF file.";
                }

    }

    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>test file</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Instant Validation</h1>
        <form action=""  method="post" 
        style="border: 1px solid green; width: 700px; height: 157px;">

        <table style="width: 800px; ">
            <col width="120"> 
            
            <tr>
                <th align="left">New File</th>
                <td style="width: 100px;"><b>:</b><INPUT ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" METHOD=POST NAME="File" TYPE="file" id="File" >
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left; color: red;" id="file"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table style="width: 800px; height: 80px;">
            <col width="120">
            <tr>
                <th align="left">Username</th>
                <td  style="width: 100px;"><b>:</b><input type="text" name="User"
                    id="User" /></td>
                <td style="text-align: left; color: red;" id="user"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="left">Password</th>
                <td  style="width: 100px;"><b>:</b><input type="password" name="Password"
                    id="Password" />
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left; color: red;" id="pass"></td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <button  style = "color: green;" type="reset" value="Reset" onClick="window.location.reload()">Clear</button><a> </a>
                <button  style = "color: green;" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="submit">Submit</button>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```